# Non elementary Integral problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

This is a difficult problem I tried to solve. But I couldn't solve it using different basic analysis theorems.

Let $f(x)= \int_0^x e^{-5t^2}dt$.

Prove that if $|x|<\frac{1}{5}$ then $|x - f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{75}$

Comment: I would try to make a Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Andrei's idea, we see that
\begin{align}
f(x)=\int^x_0 e^{-5t^2}\ dt= x+\frac{f^{(3)}(\xi(x))}{3!}x^3
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
|x-f(x)| = \left|\frac{f^{(3)}(\xi(x))}{3!}x^3 \right| < \frac{10}{3!}\frac{1}{5^3}=\frac{1}{75}.
\end{align}

Comment: Does this require showing that $\frac{f^{(5)}(\xi(x))}{5!}x^5\ge0$?

Comment: @SteveKass Yes. Just take the derivative to see that the function is positive.

Comment: That doesn’t mean the fifth derivative is positive. In fact, the fourth derivative of $e^{-5x^2}$ is negative for some $x$-values larger than $0.23$.

Comment: @SteveKass Yes. For the purpose of the problem, I think everything is okay.

Comment: I agree that everything is okay (and that, for example, you don’t need additional terms in the series), but there is definitely a bit more to show. In addition to $f^{(5)}(\xi(x))\ge0$, you need to be sure that $\frac{f^{(5)}(\xi(x))}{5!}x^5 \le 2\cdot{10\over 3!}x^3$ for your inequality to follow.

Comment: @SteveKass I have updated the solution.